# How to make comment reply query in MYSQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, comments

I am having comment reply (only till one level) functionality. All comments can have as many as replies but no replies can have their further replies.

So my database table structure is like below

```
Id    ParentId    Comment
1     0           this is come sample comment text
2     0           this is come sample comment text
3     0           this is come sample comment text
4     1           this is come sample comment text
5     0           this is come sample comment text
6     3           this is come sample comment text
7     1           this is come sample comment text
```

In the above structures, commentid, 1 (has 2 replies) and 3 (1 reply) has replies. So to fetch the comments and their replies, one simple method is first I fetch all the comments having ParentId as 0 and then by running a while loop fetch all the replies of that particular commentId. But that seems to be running hundreds of queries if I'll have around 200 comments on a particular record.

So I want to make a query which will fetch Comments with their replies sequentially as following;

```
Id    ParentId    Comment
1     0           this is come sample comment text
4     1           this is come sample comment text
7     1           this is come sample comment text
2     0           this is come sample comment text
3     0           this is come sample comment text
6     3           this is come sample comment text    
5     0           this is come sample comment text
```

I also have a comment date column in my comment table, if anyone wants to use this with comment query.

So finally I want to fetch all the comments and their replies by using one single mysql query. Please tell me how I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use an expression in an ORDER BY. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
ORDER BY IF(ParentId = 0, Id, ParentId), Id
```

This will first sort by Id, if ParentId = 0, or by ParentId otherwise. The second sort criterion is the Id, to assure that replies are returned in order.

Comment: Nice, really AWESOME, its perfect for one level reply situation.

Comment: @rodion can we make some changes in the query to order it irrespective of replies level. That means reply can also have their own replies, Some what digg is doing http://digg.com/health/Snake_Oil_Oprah ?

Comment: Prashant, to get all comments with their replies with arbitrary reply depth, you would need SQL99's WITH RECURSIVE statement. As far as I know, it is only available in Postgres and Oracle.

Comment: @rodion what if we want to limit the number of replies for each comment?

Comment: how if I wan to limit number of comment with parentId = 0 and number of comment with parentId != 0?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you restructure your database schema.  The main problem is that you are trying to treat comments and replies as the same thing, and they simple aren't the same thing.  This is forcing you to make some difficult queries.

Imagine having two tables: [COMMENTS:(id, text)], and replies to comments in another table [REPLIES(id, commentid, text)].  The problem seems much, much easier when thought of in this way.

Comment: Its not possible to change the whole table structure currently, we have to go with the current situation.

Comment: I think by making use of self join we can do this, but how I am not getting exactly ?

Answer (score -2):

If you / somebody is looking for simple solution, then it might be helpfull.

Structure Change - I suppose you have changed it by adding Blog ID, If there is no blog ID, how do you say which comments are specific to a Blog?

First do this, it won't harm anything to your database,

```
update `tblcomments` set ParentId=Id where ParentId=0;
```

then to get the blog comments and comment replies in order (comment - reply 1, reply 2... under the comment)

use the bleow query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  tblcomments 
ORDER BY  ParentId ASC;
```

Cheers,
-PM.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this would work so I tried it.
This does *not* work.

Comment: Please don't do that... This will destroy your hirarchy completly. Use @rodions answer instead! ORDER BY IF(ParentId = 0, Id, ParentId), Id