# Get repliess on in comment system

Tags: php, mysql, sql, comments

I'm working on comments system where display post, comments (parent comments), and comments repliess (child comments).

MySql comments table looks like below:

```
comment_id int primary_key
post_id int // where i save the post id 
author varchar
comment text
parent_id int // where i save parent comment id in case this comment is reply of another comment
```

Now, My case is when I go through MySql result set to print comments info. exactly when trying to print child comments (comments of other comments ) and parent comments ( comment of the post ).

My current method to achieve this, is selecting all comments that have no parent_id

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_id = null
```

And loop over all result using PHP, then make another query inside the loop for each comment searching if there is any child comments of it.

```
<?php

$sql_result_set;

while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result_set, MYSQL_ASSOC){
      // process comment info 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments where parent_id = ".$comment['comment_id'];
      $result = mysqli_query($sql);
      if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
         while($child_comments = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
               // child comments of the parent
         }
      }
}

?>
```

Now, My question is "Is there any better way to do the same thing? "

Your help is appreciated

All the best,

Comment: This would effectively select all records from the `comments` table, in a specific order. Is this what you really want to do?

Comment: You might want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/937042/1627227. It's a slightly different approach, but much more effective, than having a new database query per comment reply.

Comment: @DaveRandom no, not all of them in production will return limit number of comment

Comment: @martinCzerwi Yes, this what i'm looking for, how to expat replies from SQL limit result for example: LIMIT 10

Comment: @MohammadAhmad I'm not sure if I understand that right. Do you want to show a maximum of 10 replies per comment? If that's what you want, you'll have to do it with a subquery in MySQL. You could do it the way you wanted (with PHP loops), but performing database queries in PHP loops always performs worse, than doing a single query, even if the result is larger. Please consider learning about subqueries or use a single SELECT-query with a larger result.

Comment: @martinCzerwi so you are suggest to get all comments from database and then use php loop to limit disabled result, right?

Comment: @MohammadAhmad Yes, first select the comments, which have the **right postid** of course, then loop through the comments, and if the replies are more than 10 for example, display the last or the first 10 replies, however you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to collect all the value in an array i.e select all parent_id in above case and the use

```
WHERE IN(parent_id list)
```

Comment: ...in which case you can use a subquery to do this, like `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE parent_id = null)`

Comment: @DaveRandom this can be used in the above case also just the condition may vary

Comment: This one is very good but there is still need to make query for each comment.  stackoverflow.com/q/937042/1627227 this make it one query but there is problem with limiting results