# Comment reply query (in reverse order)

Tags: mysql, sql, comments

I found a comments query example on this site that works with perfectly with my current DB structure.

Link : [How to make comment reply query in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937042/how-to-make-comment-reply-query-in-mysql)

The accepted answer works, but I was wondering if it was possible to reverse the order so the newest comments show up first?

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
ORDER BY IF(ParentId = 0, Id, ParentId), Id
```

I tried "desc" in the query, but that messes up parent / child comment sorting.

Comment: . . Please give an example of data and how you want it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
ORDER BY IF(ParentId = 0, Id, ParentId), ParentId!=0, Id desc
```

This will sort all parents in ASC order, then all comments in DESC order, leaving each parent at the top. Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7cf95/1).

Comment: Thank you, with your examples I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. In order for the comment replies not to show up before the parent, I had to do : ORDER BY IF(ParentId = 0, Id, ParentId) desc, Id

Comment: Correction :  ORDER BY IF(ParentId = 0, Id, ParentId) desc, ParentId!=0, Id desc