# WP/MySql How Select Comments Grouped with Replies

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting, sql-order-by

I am using WordPress and trying to implement nested comments.
My table is all set with the name `wp_comments` and has the following fields:

```
comment_ID | comment_date | comment_parent, etc.
```

`comment_parent` remains equal to 0 in top level comments; it is equal to the `comment_ID` of the comment replied to in nested replies.

The original code that im using now, looks like this:

```
$wp_comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
      SELECT *
      FROM $wpdb->comments
      WHERE comment_post_ID = %d
        AND comment_approved = 1
        AND comment_type = ''
      ORDER BY comment_date
    ", $post_id));
```

but this one not nested comment, as you know.

Then I find following code here: [How to make comment reply query in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937042/how-to-make-comment-reply-query-in-mysql)

```
$wp_comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("
SELECT *
 FROM $wpdb->comments
 WHERE comment_post_ID = %d
 AND comment_approved = 1
 AND comment_type = ''
 ORDER BY IF(comment_parent = 0,  comment_ID , comment_parent)
" , $post_id ));
```

This one work fine but as there mention just **"perfect for one level reply situation"**.

So how fetch all the comments and their replies in nested way by using one single query?

Thanks

Comment: The field "comment_parent" resides in the same table, yes?

Comment: yes, all of them resides in the same table.